# Dialog resource as a main form

Tags: c++, winapi

When using dialog resource as a main form for a Win32 Desktop application should one create a main form too or is creating a dialog and message handler for a dialog sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating the dialog by itself is sufficient.